# How can I filter calendar events with a specific email address or name using Microsoft graph api and OData?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata

I'm using the Microsoft graph api to fetch calendar events.
Now I would like to only fetch events where one of the attendees has a specific name or email address.
An example response describing such an event is

```json
{
  "subject": "General meeting",
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "Peter Pan",
        "address": "peter.pan@neverland.org"
      }
    },
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "name": "Captain Hook",
        "address": "captain.hook@neverland.org"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

According to [Microsofts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters) the likely way to achieve this is using OData and the `any` operator. However I can't find a way to access nested properties like `name` and `address` using query parameters.

I was hoping I could do something like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&enddatetime=2022-31-01T00:00:00.000Z&$select=attendees,subject&$filter=attendees/any(var:var/emailAddress/address eq 'peter.pan@neverland.org')
```

but using subparam (`emailAddress/address`) like that leads to bad request.

If the `emailAddress` field was just an actual email and not another entity, filtering would work.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview?startdatetime=2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&enddatetime=2022-31-01T00:00:00.000Z&$select=attendees,subject&$filter=attendees/any(var:var/emailAddress eq 'peter.pan@neverland.org')
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1771?msclkid=fb1d8df8b7fb11ec8238d3ee26457d27#issuecomment-410301969) comment Graph API doesn't support drilling down multiple levels of relationships.